# How to convert a python dictionary to an 2D array and pad wherever there is mismatch in length?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to put dictionary items into an array. The keys are all integer numbers and each value is a list of different length however. I'd like to convert to an array and padd with zeros. I've got the following which

```
a = {1:[0, 1], 2:[21], 3:[]}
lmax = 0
for item in a.values():
    lmax = len(item) if len(item) > lmax else lmax
t = np.zeros(len(a), lmax)
for key in a:
    t[ key, :len(a[key]) ] = a[key]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up keys and values in your code, so I'm not sure how that could work.

One way of doing this is

```
a = {1:[0, 1], 2:[21], 3:[]}
max_length = max(len(item) for item in a.values())
t = [[0] * (max_length - len(item)) + item for item in a.values()]
```

Or if you want to ensure that the list is in the 'right' order - i.e., the item with the lowest key in the original dictionary appears first - you can alter this to

```
t = [[0] * (max_length - len(item)) + item for _, item in sorted(a.items())]
```

Comment: Yeah I think I fixed the mistake in the 2nd for loop.

Answer (score 0):

for lmax,

```
lmax = max(map(len, a.values()))
```